# How to increase the number of recent file listings in helm-mini?

Tags: init-file, helm, recentf

Is there a way to configure the number of recent files that will be in the `Recentf` section of a `helm-mini` buffer?

Comment: You might try customizing `recentf-max-saved-items`

Comment: doesnt work in helm atm.